# remove duplicates/loops from graph data

Tags: sql, t-sql, teradata

I have graph data where the arcs (consisting of start [S] and end [E]) of the graph are stored as follows in a relational table:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Test') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Test;

CREATE TABLE #Test
(
    S NVARCHAR(1)   
    ,E NVARCHAR(1)
);

insert into #Test (S, E) values ('a', 'b');
insert into #Test (S, E) values ('b', 'a');
insert into #Test (S, E) values ('a', 'c');
```

So the graph consists of these arcs:

```
a -> b
b -> a
a -> c
```

I would like to remove duplicates/cycles: a -> b and b -> a => a -> b. Is this possible?

Comment: do you want to delete them after insertion or insert only one such pair into the table?

Comment: Either way is fine. Let us say #Test is a staging table and non cyclic/de duplicated data is written into #Test1.

Comment: @shA.t this is no duplicate!

Comment: sorry my Bad ;).

Comment: Actually Delete those cycles or just don't Select? What about cycles like `a->b, b->c, c->a`? Is this for your previous question?

Answer (score 3):

**Example**

```
;with cte as (
    Select *
          ,RN = Row_Number() over (Partition By case when S<E then S+E else E+S end order by s,e)
     From  #Test
)
Delete From cte Where RN>1
```

**Updated Test**

```
S   E
a   b
a   c
```

Comment: @csetzkorn The only trick is create the normalized pairs via the case.  Then Row_Number() will handle the duplicate pairs

Comment: as s and e are characters can S<E etc. work? I get bad character in format

Comment: @csetzkorn Little confused.  I used your #test data/structure

Comment: @csetzkorn Sorry, not a teradata guy.  Pretty sure teradata supports Row_Number().  Not sure if it would support the delete via a cte.

Comment: well ctes are a bit iffy in teradata but i would use a staging table for this anyway. < for characters definitely does not work. May have to introduce a fake integer primary index. as this involves a little bit of work I can onlo check tomorrow ... sorry

Comment: @csetzkorn No apologies.  I'm sure you will find the solution for teradata.  Perhaps if you tag your question with teradata, I'm sure there is someone who can better assist.

Comment: Doesn't work in Teradata, because you can't Delete from a CTE.

Comment: @dnoeth Thanks for the confirmation.  OP also mentioned a < string comparison.  Is this truly not a valid operaion in teradata?

Comment: @JohnCappelletti: Of course `'S'<'E'` works, but the `+` is proprietary T-SQL, concatenating strings is done in Standard SQL using `||`. For Teradata `+` is a numeric operator and trying cast `S` into a numeric value obviously fails :-)

Comment: @dnoeth Goodness I knew that... Just never occured to me to connect the dots.   Post your solution.  I'm sure OP would appreciate it.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti: If there are actual cycles like `a->b, b->c, c->a` there's no simple solution :-)

Comment: The concatenation thing completely threw me off. + is a commutative operator in math so order doesn't matter and the CASE clause became meaningless to me. Reading the comments, it makes more sense that you mean concatenation rather than summing numbers.

Comment: @Bobort There is no summing here.  We're dealing with strings.  It is a simple logic switch to get unique combinations (NOT permutations) so  a>b  is essentially the same as b>a.  OP tagged teradata after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

If you only got simple duplicates like your example:

```
DELETE
FROM #test AS t1
WHERE EXISTS
 ( SELECT *
   FROM #test AS t2
   WHERE t1.S = t2.E -- there's the same S/E combination, but switched
     AND t1.E = t2.S
     AND t1.S > t2.S -- delete only one of the combinations
 )
```